# Gradle is selecting wrong dependency version

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, hibernate-validator, maven-central

I am seeing some weirdness in my Gradle build. I have a Spring Boot app (which uses Gradle for its build) and am trying to pull in both the Hibernate Validator as well as Hibernate Core. Here's the `dependencies` declaration in my `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
        exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }

    compile(
        'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.12'
        ,'com.google.inject:guice:4.1.0'
        ,'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3'
        ,'org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.25'
        ,'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.9.1'
        ,'commons-cli:commons-cli:1.4'
        ,'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.7'
        ,'io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:3.2.5'
        ,'io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-json:3.2.5'
        ,'org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt:1.0.9.RELEASE'
        ,'org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.2.1.RELEASE'
        ,'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.0'
        ,'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:6.0.7.Final'
        ,'mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.6'
        ,'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.12.Final'

        ,'com.h2database:h2:1.4.196'

        ,'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty'
        ,'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
        ,'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
        ,'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
        ,'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    )

    dev('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')

    testCompile(
        'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4'
        ,'junit:junit:4.12'
    )
}
```

When I run `./gradlew dependencies` I get a huge output, but from the `compile` dependencies tree I see the following:

```
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.5.8.RELEASE
|    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.3.5.Final -> 6.0.7.Final
|    |    \--- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.0.7.Final
|    |         +--- javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final -> 1.1.0.Final
|    |         +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final -> 3.3.1.Final
|    |         \--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.3.1 -> 1.3.4
```

So to me it looks like `spring-boot-starter:1.5.8.RELEASE` is pulling in `validation-api:2.0.1.Final` but for some reason Gradle is selecting `validation-api:1.1.0.Final` for me...am I reading that correctly? In my IDE compile classpath I only see `validation-api:1.1.0.Final`, not `2.0.1.Final`.

**Why is Gradle selecting `1.1.0.Final` instead of `2.0.1.Final`?** I ask because Hibernate Validator 5.x [is not compatible with Validation API 1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24652819/4009451) and when my app runs I get all sorts of Hibernate Validation-related errors.

### Update

Some more output:

```
gradle -q dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency validation-api
javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final (selected by rule)

javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final -> 1.1.0.Final
\--- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.0.7.Final
     \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:6.0.7.Final
          +--- compile
          \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.8.RELEASE
               +--- compile
               \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:1.5.8.RELEASE
                    \--- compile
```

The full compile configuration output [can be found here](https://pastebin.com/CQLY3tDp).

Comment: Post the complete tree of the compile configuration. Also consider using dependencyInsight (http://mrhaki.blogspot.fr/2014/08/gradle-goodness-getting-more-dependency.html) and posting the output.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet (+1) - please see my pastebin link added to the top of this question. I also added the output of `dependencyInsigh` for the `validation-api` library if that helps you! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version is enforced by Spring Boot.

See the POM for the Spring Boot dependencies: http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/1.5.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-1.5.8.RELEASE.pom and look for "javax-validation.version".

See https://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/Brussels-SR4/reference/html/getting-started-overriding-versions.html for more information on how to override Spring Boot versions.

I would recommend overriding directly "javax-validation.version" and "hibernate-validator.version" instead of redefining the dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @Guaillaume (+1) I've never done this before (directly overriding javax.validation.version + hibernate-validator.version). Is this something I do in build.gradle or in application.yml?

Comment: See the link I gave you, you have a paragraph about how to override the versions with Gradle: https://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/Brussels-SR4/reference/html/getting-started-overriding-versions.html#getting-started-overriding-versions-gradle .

Comment: Thanks I see it, so this `ext['foo.version'] = '1.1.0.RELEASE'` declaration, do I put that inside my `dependencies` declaration in Gradle, or do I put it outside that declaration (maybe above it, etc.)?

Comment: I'm more of a Maven guy, but I would say at the root of the build.gradle above the dependencies declaration (ah and use javax.validation.version, not foo.version ;)).

Comment: The override for gradle as described in the docs didn't work for me. This however did: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6507

Answer (score 1):

There is some conflict with another dependency that is pulling the older 1.1.0 in the compile classpath.

This means that some other library which has higher priority in gradle build order is dependent the older 1.1.0 version.

You can see here [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242415/how-to-specify-gradle-build-execution-order) on how to specify the gradle build order.

Comment: Thanks @Tal (+1) - please see my pastebin link added to the top of this question. I also added the output of dependencyInsigh for the validation-api library if that helps you! Thanks again!

Comment: Also @Tal according to the output of all these dependency trees, `org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.0.7.Final` is the only thing pulling in `validation-api`...

Comment: Pay attention that hibernate version 5.x.x . pulls down  javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final and I see you have also org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.12.Final

Comment: Thanks @Tal but I'm not understanding you... it *sounds* like you're saying that `org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.12.Final` pulls down `validation-api:1.1.0.Final` but I don't see evidence of that in my dependency tree. Can you elaboriate a bit more?

Comment: Yo have--- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.3.5.Final -> 6.0.7.Final
    |    |    \--- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.0.7.Final

Answer (score 0):

I met similar problems, then I found it caused by using the Dependency management in gradle:

```
plugins {
     ...
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Hoxton.SR8"
    }
}
```

this dependency management impact the transitive dependency version solution. after comment it out. all the version is correct.